# count only first occurrence

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I wonder if someone could help as I have been stumped on this for some time.
I have a excel spreadsheet with multiple pages.
On the "master sheet" i have several columns....

- A is week number
- K is school year group
- F is a unique pupil number

on another page I have the following code:

```
  =COUNTIFS('Master Sheet 2021-2022'!A:A,"1", 'Master Sheet 2021-2022'!K:K,"Year  7")
```

This brings back a return of a number. EG on week 1 we had 25 days of year 7s (of these 25 it could be that students are counted more than once)

I want to do the same BUT instead of 25 days I want to know how many individual students
EG on week 1 we had 18 individual year 7s (25 days worth, but only 18 students)

Hope that makes sense and someone can help.
Pete

Answer (score 0):

Good Day Pete,

This example in the image below should provide you a starting point for your solution.

The formula in F3 provides Unique students in week 1, the second is unique students in grade 7 in week 1.

[image]

I hope this helps,
Brad

Comment: Thank you for your help on this however it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a job for a Pivot Table, using a tiny bit of the Power Pivot functionality.
Select your data (which ideally wants to be in a table, but any range will also be fine).

**Insert > Pivot Table**. In the dialog box, select the check box to "**Add this Data to the Data Model**". This is crucial.
Now build your Pivot Table as usual, something like:

[image: Pivot table with weeks as rows and year group as columns, counting student UPNs]

Click on the Count of UPN dropdown and select **Value Field Settings**. In the dialog box, scroll down to the very bottom of the list of choices for summarizing the data and select "**Distinct Count**".

This option is only available if your data was added to the data model.

Click OK. Job done.

Comment: Fantastic, this works a treat, thank you so much as I have been trying with this for ages. I have done the pivot table, and from there it fills in other pages of the document. The only thing is it does not do it automatically, I have to manually refresh the pivot table, but that is not the end of the world, I will just refresh every time I open it. Thank you for you help. Pete

Comment: @Pete Right click > PivotTable options > Data tab > Refresh data when opening the file.
That doesn't keep it refreshed as you change data but at least it makes sure other users get a clean version every time they open it

Comment: Wow, I thought I was a whiz at excel, and I am compared to some, but I would not have known how to do all this. Thank you all very much for your help. Pete